# Redux + Apollo: How to normalize and format response data?

Tags: javascript, react-redux, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am facing a difficulty getting data into my components in the format I would like.

**My data comes through as:**

[image]

Which is not in a very usable format for my component. I'd like for the data to be keyed by id as suc:

```
assets: {
  "2a4a34sdf3dd": {
    //asset data
  }
}
```

My query is:

```
const query = gql`{
  assets {
    body
    id
  }
}`
```

And I connect my component as such:

```
export default compose(
  graphql(query),
  connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
)(AssetList);
```

Any insight into how I can format my store data returned by my graphql server?

Comment: Why not make a formatting helper that wraps mapStateToProps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apollo has its own Redux store format, and you can map it into a shape consumable by the component using the `graphql` HOC. It passes down the props to the child component in the same shape as the query, see the example on the home page: http://dev.apollodata.com/

However, you can still control the keys for the data in the store by passing a `dataIdFromObject` function. For example, if you have unique `id` fields on all of your objects you can simply use:

```
new ApolloClient({
  dataIdFromObject: ({ id }) => id,
  ... other options
});
```

See more docs about this here: http://dev.apollodata.com/react/cache-updates.html#dataIdFromObject

Basically, while Apollo uses Redux as the storage for GraphQL data, the store format is not meant to be consumed by components directly. Instead, think of the `graphql` HOC as a pre-made Redux selector you can use to efficiently get that data into your UI.

By the way, if you want to view your store in a more GraphQL-oriented way, you can use the recently released Apollo dev tools: https://github.com/apollostack/apollo-client-devtools

Comment: Beautiful answer. Thank you. I missed that very crucial details in the docs.

Comment: Is this still the case for Apollo ^2.0? It seems Redux is not supported anymore.